# Can you help me to correct this query in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregation

```
SELECT 
    STUDENT_NAME, SUBJECT, TYPE_OF_DISTRIBUTION, 
    SUM(POINTS) * WEIGHT_IN_PERCENTAGE / (COUNT(POINTS) * 100)
FROM 
    assignments a 
JOIN
    distributions d ON a.TYPE_OF_DISTRIBUTION = d.ASSIGNMENT_CATEGORY
GROUP BY
    SUBJECT, TYPE_OF_DISTRIBUTION, STUDENT_NAME 
ORDER BY
    STUDENT_NAME ASC;
```

> ERROR at line 1:
> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error for `WEIGHT_IN_PERCENTAGE`. If `WEIGHT_IN_PERCENTAGE` is same for every row in a group you can use `(SUM(POINTS) * max(WEIGHT_IN_PERCENTAGE))` or you can `SUM(POINTS*WEIGHT_IN_PERCENTAGE)` multiply it with `POINTS` before sum:

```
SELECT 
    STUDENT_NAME, SUBJECT, TYPE_OF_DISTRIBUTION, 
    SUM(POINTS) * max(WEIGHT_IN_PERCENTAGE) / (COUNT(POINTS) * 100)
FROM 
    assignments a 
JOIN
    distributions d ON a.TYPE_OF_DISTRIBUTION = d.ASSIGNMENT_CATEGORY
GROUP BY
    SUBJECT, TYPE_OF_DISTRIBUTION, STUDENT_NAME 
ORDER BY
    STUDENT_NAME ASC;
```

OR

```
SELECT 
    STUDENT_NAME, SUBJECT, TYPE_OF_DISTRIBUTION, 
    SUM(POINTS * WEIGHT_IN_PERCENTAGE) / (COUNT(POINTS) * 100)
FROM 
    assignments a 
JOIN
    distributions d ON a.TYPE_OF_DISTRIBUTION = d.ASSIGNMENT_CATEGORY
GROUP BY
    SUBJECT, TYPE_OF_DISTRIBUTION, STUDENT_NAME 
ORDER BY
    STUDENT_NAME ASC;
```